# Chrome extension. Get element after redirect with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

manifest.json:

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,

"name": "Name",
"description": "Description",
"version": "1.0",

"browser_action": {
    "name": "Manipulate DOM",
    "icons": ["icon.png"],
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "index.html"
},
"content_scripts": [ {
    "js": [ "jquery.min.js", "custom.js" ],
    "matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*"]
  }],
"permissions": [
    "activeTab", "tabs", "<all_urls>", "webRequest "
]}
```

custom.js:

```
function hello() {
chrome.tabs.executeScript({
    file: 'alert.js'
}); 
}
document.getElementById('clickme').addEventListener('click', hello);
```

alert.js:

```
$('input[name="firstname"]').val('Alex');
$('input[name="lastname"]').val('Jefferson');
$('button[name="submit"]').trigger('click');
```

After trigger('click'), a redirect to another page with second form.
How can I fill a second form?
"$('#elem').val();" does not work in new page.

**UPD:** my background.js code:

```
function secondStep() { 
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "secondStep.js"}); 
    chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.removeListener(boundX); 
} 

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) { 
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "firstStep.js"}, function() { 
        var boundX = secondStep.bind(); 
        chrome.webNavigation.onCommitted.addListener(boundX);   
    }); 
});
```

Comment: You can add chrome.webNavigation.onCommitted listener inside executeScript's callback, and in that listener run your second content script using another executeScript. Don't forget to remove the added listener!

Comment: @wOxxOm, thank you very much! It works. How can I correctly remove listener? My code in UPD section.